Unity: Animations Work in Animator Window but Character Freezes in Scene When Switching Animations via Coroutine
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class CreatureController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator; 
    public float speed = 3.0f;
    //public float turnSpeed = 200.0f; 
    public Vector3 boundaryMin; 
    public Vector3 boundaryMax; 

    private bool isWalking = false;
    private Vector3 targetDirection;

    private readonly string[] animationParameters = { "walk", "idle2", "sniff", "roar", "crouch" };

    void Start()
    {
        if (animator == null)
        {
            animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        }
        targetDirection = transform.forward;

        SetRandomStartingPosition();
        StartCoroutine(PlayRandomAnimation());
    }

    void Update()
    {
        isWalking = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Creep|Walk1_Action") || 
                    animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Creep|Crouch_Action");

        if (isWalking)
        {
            MoveCreature();
        }
    }
    
    void SetRandomStartingPosition()
    {
        float randomX = Random.Range(boundaryMin.x, boundaryMax.x);
        float randomZ = Random.Range(boundaryMin.z, boundaryMax.z);
        transform.position = new Vector3(randomX, transform.position.y, randomZ);
    }

    void MoveCreature()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
        //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);

        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        if (position.x < boundaryMin.x || position.x > boundaryMax.x || position.z < boundaryMin.z || position.z > boundaryMax.z)
        {
            Vector3 directionToCenter = (new Vector3((boundaryMin.x + boundaryMax.x) / 2, position.y, (boundaryMin.z + boundaryMax.z) / 2) - position).normalized;
            targetDirection = directionToCenter;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator PlayRandomAnimation()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, animationParameters.Length);
            string chosenAnimation = animationParameters[randomIndex];

            foreach (string parameter in animationParameters)
            {
                animator.SetBool(parameter, false);
            }

            animator.SetBool(chosenAnimation, true);
            Debug.Log($"Playing animation: {chosenAnimation}");

            float waitTime = Random.Range(2.0f, 5.0f);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

            if (chosenAnimation == "Creep|Walk1_Action" || chosenAnimation == "Creep|Crouch_Action")
            {
                targetDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0, Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f)).normalized;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Triggered by: " + other.name);  
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            animator.SetBool("attack", true);
        }
    }
}

A coroutine should play each animation. I tried to succeed however only the default animation was playing in the scene. When it switches to other animations by boolean parameters, animations stop playing and the character freezes. I expect a coroutine to start and animations will be played randomly until a player gets closer enough to attack them.

You probably have one property inside the in use animation clips recorded. You need to remove it if you are going to change it via Script.
